# boto3 attached device name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get the device name where an EBS volume is attached.  I can pull the attach data, but would just like to isolate the device name.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import ClientError

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

filters = [{
      'Name': 'tag:app',
      'Values': [ 'splunklogidx' ],
      'Name': 'tag:splunksnap',
      'Values': [ 'yes' ]
      }]

#volumes = ec2.volumes.all()  # list all volumes
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=filters)  # list all volumes

for v in volumes:
   print "v.id = %s" % v.id
   #print "v.tags = %s" % v.tags
   print "v.attachments = %s" % v.attachments

  #for atDev in v.attachments:
      #if atDev['Key'] == 'Device':
         #print "device = %s" % atDev['Value']
```

And example of the output is below, and I would like to just be able to pull the `/dev/sda1` from that.
Thank You, K.

```
v.attachments = [
{u'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 11, 10, 35, 8, tzinfo=tzutc()),
u'InstanceId': 'i-004821f294d20085d', 
u'VolumeId': 'vol-069d956bf5076c68d', 
u'State': 'attached', 
u'DeleteOnTermination': True, 
u'Device': '/dev/sda1'}
]
```

Comment: is there any reason why not to use just `v.attachments[0][u'Device']`?

Comment: Yes.  I am picking up python, and still learning the nuances.  That was the answer I needed.  Thank You.